# Можно ли принудительно завершить работу std::sort?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, poco

У меня есть основной поток, который содержит в себе бесконечный цикл, который дожидается другой поток, занимающийся сортировкой.

```
// Инициализация потока для работы с сортировкой файла
const poco::Runnable::Ptr sortingRunnable(new SortingRunnable(this));
poco::Thread sortingThread;

// Флаг, отсортирован ли файл
_isSorted = false;

// Запуск сортировки 
sortingThread.start(sortingRunnable);

// Выставление ProgressBar в бесконечное состояние
_processForm->showProgress();
_processForm->initProgress(0, 0);

// Скрываем поля, оставив только ProgressBar
_processForm->hideLabelsAndCounters();

// Перерисовываем ProgressBar для прокрутки "бесконечной" загрузки
for (;;)
{
    _processForm->repaintProgress();

    // Если файл будет отсортирован, но выходим из цикла
    if (_isSorted)
        break;

    // Если во время сортировки файла, пользователь нажмёт ( Отмена ), то прозводим выход 
    checkApplicationMessage();

    // Принудительно вызываю обработку накопившихся событий
    QApplication::processEvents();
}

// Ждём поток, отвечающий за сортировку
sortingThread.join();
```

Как можете видеть я создаю Runnable библиотеки poco, и в нём вызываю асинхронную сортировку. Соотвественно я и дожидаюсь результата этой сортировки в бексонечном цикле цикле. Сама сортировка вот:

```
class SortingRunnable : public poco::Runnable {
public:
explicit SortingRunnable(ImportMaster* import) : _import(import) {}
~SortingRunnable() {}
void run() override
{
    auto sorting = [&](const QStringList& str1, const QStringList& str2) -> bool
    {
        if (str1.empty() || str2.empty())
            return false;

        QChar char1;
        QChar char2;

        if (!str1[0].isEmpty() && !str2[0].isEmpty())
        {
            char1 = str1[0][0];
            char2 = str2[0][0];
        }

        const poco::UInt8 SYMBOL = 0x0000007E;

        if ((char1 == SYMBOL && char2 == SYMBOL) || (char1 != SYMBOL && char2 != SYMBOL))
            return naturalSorting(str1.join(',').toStdString(), str2.join(',').toStdString());

        if (char1 != SYMBOL && char2 == SYMBOL)
            return false;

        if (char1 == SYMBOL && char2 != SYMBOL)
            return true;

        return false;
    };

    std::sort(_import->_strings.begin(), _import->_strings.end(), sorting);

    _import->_isSorted = true;
}

private:
    ImportMaster* _import;
};
```

Теперь основной вопрос. Функция checkApplicationMessage(); вызывает обработку отмены процесса импорта, который в основной поток кидает исключение, которое я могу успешно отловить и обработать как мне нужно. Но как мне сказать потоку Runnable остановить процесс std::sort (сортировки)?

Comment: так раз у вас сортировка в отдельном потоке, почему бы вам не остановить выполнение этого потока?

Comment: "Вы предлагаете бросать исключение из потока где происходит сортировка?" - я не понимаю где вы это прочитали? Я еще раз прочитал свой комментарий и не нашел вообще никакого упоминания об исключениях... Что касается же "остановить выполнение потока" - то да, это я и написал! Это можно сделать просто вызвав деструктор потока (по крайней мере если речь идет о std::thread)

Comment: Но вынужден заметить, что у вас сдесь скорее всего ошибка проектирования - мне сложно представить что вы хотите добится и как это должно работать, не говоря уж о целостности данных

Comment: ну слушайте, вот вы возмущаетесь тем, что вы задали "предельно простой вопрос", но вас почему-то не устраивает "предельно простой ответ": остановить выполнение потока. `std::thread` приведен в качестве примера (тем более что это часть стандарной библиотеки) - если вам нужено знать как это реализовать в `poco::Thread` - обращайтесь к документации, за вас этого никто не сделает. Что касается ошибки проектирования - во-превых это предположение, во-вторых вы очень наивны если думаете, что для выявления ошибок проектирования нужно видеть весь код проекта.

Comment: что же касается "оффтопа" и "не знаете ответа на вопрос" - то вынужден заметить, что с таким отношением вы вряд ли от кого-то добьетесь помощи, скорее только настроите против себя более опытных участников сообщества, которые пытаются вам помочь

Comment: во-первых, научитесь все-таки читать то что пишут другие - я ничего не писал о том, чтобы вы использовали std::thread вместо poco::thread (окуда вы вообще это все берете?), во-вторых, если вы всерьез срашиваете как остановить выполнение конекретной функции `std::sort` - вам пора садится за учебник и начать изучать основы программирования.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch *"Это можно сделать просто вызвав деструктор потока (по крайней мере если речь идет о std::thread)"* Не знаю про poco, но деструктор `std::thread` дергает `std::terminate`, если до него не были вызваны `join()` или `detach()`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat да, верно

Comment: @TimurLikhomanov *"каким образом остановить выполнение std::sort?"* Дождаться, пока оно досортирует, не вариант? В мануале на `Poco::Thread` на первый взгляд не нашел ничего для остановки потока. Можно попробовать в комапарторе `std::sort` проверять какой-то флажок, и если что, кинуть исключение. Но я не могу найти информацию, можно ли так делать.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, к сожалению в этом и проблема, что дождаться и нельзя. Я поэтому и пытаюсь это проблему решить и ничего лучше не придумал как бросать исключение в std::sort внутри лямда-функции.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, P.s почему дождаться нельзя? После того как пользователь отменит процесс импорта окно программы должно закрыться, следственно должна остановиться и сортировка. (К сожалению ожидание сортировки очень долгий процесс, ибо строк может быть свыше нескольких миллионов, что достаточно долгий процесс сортировки занимает)

Comment: к вопросу об ошибках проектирования - теребонькать руками `QAppliacion::processEvents` это плохая практика

Comment: @Bearded Beaver, а по другому никак. Потому что нужно, чтобы обновление progressBar`a было постоянным, ибо QT обновляет только тогда когда накопится определённое количество событий. И прямой вызов ивентов не совсем и плохо насколько мне объяснили.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Решением для данной задачи я нашёл один путь. На просторах интернета обнаружил, что можно кидать исключения в std::sort обработке. Что я и сделал, создал атомарный флаг, который выставляется во время выброса исключения.

```
void run() override
{
    auto sorting = [&](const QStringList& str1, const QStringList& str2) -> bool
    {
        if (_import->_isSortedStoped)
            throw poco::Exception("Stoped sorting");

        if (str1.empty() || str2.empty())
            return false;

        QChar char1;
        QChar char2;

        if (!str1[0].isEmpty() && !str2[0].isEmpty())
        {
            char1 = str1[0][0];
            char2 = str2[0][0];
        }

        const poco::UInt8 SYMBOL = 0x0000007E;

        if ((char1 == SYMBOL && char2 == SYMBOL) || (char1 != SYMBOL && char2 != SYMBOL))
            return naturalSorting(str1.join(',').toStdString(), str2.join(',').toStdString());

        if (char1 != SYMBOL && char2 == SYMBOL)
            return false;

        if (char1 == SYMBOL && char2 != SYMBOL)
            return true;

        return false;
    };

    try
    {
        std::sort(_import->_strings.begin(), _import->_strings.end(), sorting);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        _import->_isSorted = true;
        return;
    }

    _import->_isSorted = true;
}
```

Для ловли исключения в основном потоке создал обёртку над функцией и разорвал поток обработки detach`ем.

```
// Инициализация потока для работы с сортировкой файла
const poco::Runnable::Ptr sortingRunnable(new SortingRunnable(this));
poco::Thread sortingThread;

// Флаг, отсортирован ли файл
_isSorted = false;
_isSortedStoped = false;

// Запуск сортировки 
sortingThread.start(sortingRunnable);
sortingThread.detach();

// Выставление ProgressBar в бесконечное состояние
_processForm->showProgress();
_processForm->initProgress(0, 0);

// Скрываем поля, оставив только ProgressBar
_processForm->hideLabelsAndCounters();

// Перерисовываем ProgressBar для прокрутки "бесконечной" загрузки
for (;;)
{
    _processForm->repaintProgress();

    // Если файл будет отсортирован, но выходим из цикла
    if (_isSorted)
        break;

    // Если во время сортировки файла, пользователь нажмёт ( Отмена ), то прозводим выход 
    try
    {
        checkApplicationMessage();
    }
    catch (poco::Exception& ex)
    {
        _isSortedStoped = true;
        throw ex;
    }

        // Принудительно вызываю обработку накопившихся событий
    QApplication::processEvents();
}

if (sortingThread.joinable())
    // Ждём поток, отвечающий за сортировку
    sortingThread.join();
```

Теперь всё стало работать как мне и нужно было.